# ZK: Set page title dynamically

Tags: zk

I'm using MVVM and I'm trying to set the page title dynamically based on the displayed content. When I try to change the title to a fixed string, it works:

```
<?page title="My title"?>
```

However, if I try to change it to a value from the viewmodel, it fails (the title is empty):

```
<?page title=${vm.titleProperty} ?>
```

I also tried data binding using `@init`:

```
<?page title=@init(vm.titleProperty) ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would work, you could consider all these ways to access the page object in the VM:

```
@Command
myCommand(@ContextParam(ContextType.PAGE) Page page){...
```

or

```
Executions.getCurrent().getDesktop().getFirstPage()
```

or

```
myCommand(@ContextParam(ContextType.DESKTOP) Desktop desktop )
...
desktop.getFirstPage()
```

All of those will let you access the page in the VM.

Or even better, you can register a client command and do the page change on client when the client command is fired. This is slightly more complicated, but it's better at following the mvvm pattern, since the view is completely decoupled from the VM. Example here:
http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3nmad2u/2-page-title-mvvm

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. In the viewmodel (java), you can use this code to set the page title:

```
Executions.getCurrent().getDesktop().getFirstPage().setTitle("Dynamic title");
```